# How to draw boxes around graph nodes by default

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

I am making some not so simple flow diagrams with the `graphdrawing` package and I want to draw a box around each node.

Is this possible while preserving the simple syntax? If so, how?

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[tree layout, grow=down] % somehow make each node have a box around it by putting an option here?
{
Enter the tavern -> Like each other -> Go adventuring,
Enter the tavern -> Hate each other -> Fight,
Go adventuring -> Utter defeat., 
Go adventuring -> Find treasure -> Utter defeat.,
Fight -> Utter defeat.,
Find treasure <-> Sell treasure,
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the line

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
```

[image]

Obtained by running `lualatex` on:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}] % <<<<<<<<
\graph[tree layout, grow=down]
{
Enter the tavern -> Like each other -> Go adventuring,
Enter the tavern -> Hate each other -> Fight,
Go adventuring -> Utter defeat., 
Go adventuring -> Find treasure -> Utter defeat.,
Fight -> Utter defeat.,
Find treasure <-> Sell treasure,
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works a little? It would be good to understand so that it's possible to extend in the future.

Comment: For tikz, the labels in your graph are nodes that carry a label. By default the nodes are rectangles, a bit larger than the labels, which are not drawn (thus invisible). The `every node` style can be used to change the defaults for all nodes simultaneously. The `draw` keyword makes the borders of the nodes visible. There are further options that you can use to influence e.g. shape and colour (background and text) of the nodes. For details see section 17 of the [tikz/pgf manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to style nodes in graphs is to use the `nodes` key for graphs.

For example, to draw the borders of all nodes in this graph, add `nodes=draw`:

```
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\RequirePackage{luatex85}}{}
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[tree layout, grow=down, nodes=draw] % somehow make each node have a box around it by putting an option here?
  {
    Enter the tavern -> Like each other -> Go adventuring,
    Enter the tavern -> Hate each other -> Fight,
    Go adventuring -> Utter defeat.,
    Go adventuring -> Find treasure -> Utter defeat.,
    Fight -> Utter defeat.,
    Find treasure <-> Sell treasure,
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bordered nodes]

Depending on whether you use `every node` or `graphs/nodes`, more or fewer nodes will be affected. Moreover, whether you pass the option to `\graph` or the `tikzpicture` will also affect the result.

Here are three possibilities:

1. Add `nodes=draw` to `\graph` -> nodes in this graph affected.
2. Add `graphs/nodes=draw` to `tikzpicture` -> nodes in all graphs affected.
3. Add `every node/.append style=draw` to `tikzpicture` -> all regular nodes in this picture affected (but not e.g. labels etc.).

Here's the difference:

[image: node influences]

Code:

```
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\RequirePackage{luatex85}}{}
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[tree layout, grow=down, nodes=draw] % somehow make each node have a box around it by putting an option here?
  {
    Enter the tavern -> Like each other -> Go adventuring,
    Enter the tavern -> Hate each other -> Fight,
    Go adventuring -> Utter defeat.,
    Go adventuring -> Find treasure -> Utter defeat.,
    Fight -> Utter defeat.,
    Find treasure <-> Sell treasure,
  };
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-50mm]
  \graph[tree layout, grow=down] % somehow make each node have a box around it by putting an option here?
  {
    Fly a kite -> Enjoy the sunshine -> Learn Mandarin,
    Fly a kite -> Hate the rain -> Hibernate,
    Learn Mandarin -> Impress the Empress.,
    Learn Mandarin -> Insult the Emperor -> Abandoned in jail.,
    Hibernate -> Horrendous nightmares.,
    Hibernate <-> Sweet dreams,
  };
  \end{scope}
  \node [font=\ttfamily, anchor=north, label=below:{as option to \ttfamily\textbackslash graph}] at ([yshift=-5mm]current bounding box.south) {nodes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graphs/nodes=draw]
  \graph[tree layout, grow=down] % somehow make each node have a box around it by putting an option here?
  {
    Enter the tavern -> Like each other -> Go adventuring,
    Enter the tavern -> Hate each other -> Fight,
    Go adventuring -> Utter defeat.,
    Go adventuring -> Find treasure -> Utter defeat.,
    Fight -> Utter defeat.,
    Find treasure <-> Sell treasure,
  };
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-50mm]
  \graph[tree layout, grow=down] % somehow make each node have a box around it by putting an option here?
  {
    Fly a kite -> Enjoy the sunshine -> Learn Mandarin,
    Fly a kite -> Hate the rain -> Hibernate,
    Learn Mandarin -> Impress the Empress.,
    Learn Mandarin -> Insult the Emperor -> Abandoned in jail.,
    Hibernate -> Horrendous nightmares.,
    Hibernate <-> Sweet dreams,
  };
  \end{scope}
  \node [font=\ttfamily, anchor=north, label=below:as global option] at ([yshift=-5mm]current bounding box.south) {graphs/nodes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style=draw]
  \graph[tree layout, grow=down] % somehow make each node have a box around it by putting an option here?
  {
    Enter the tavern -> Like each other -> Go adventuring,
    Enter the tavern -> Hate each other -> Fight,
    Go adventuring -> Utter defeat.,
    Go adventuring -> Find treasure -> Utter defeat.,
    Fight -> Utter defeat.,
    Find treasure <-> Sell treasure,
  };
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-50mm]
  \graph[tree layout, grow=down] % somehow make each node have a box around it by putting an option here?
  {
    Fly a kite -> Enjoy the sunshine -> Learn Mandarin,
    Fly a kite -> Hate the rain -> Hibernate,
    Learn Mandarin -> Impress the Empress.,
    Learn Mandarin -> Insult the Emperor -> Abandoned in jail.,
    Hibernate -> Horrendous nightmares.,
    Hibernate <-> Sweet dreams,
  };
  \end{scope}
  \node [font=\ttfamily, anchor=north, label=below:but not labels] at ([yshift=-5mm]current bounding box.south) {every node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```